# Which one is better as POCO model property: ForeignKey/ID or Object reference?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0, poco

Hi I am starting using EF 4.1 and POCO in the project I am working on. The model I am using looks like this:

```
 public class Contact1
    {
        // Primary key
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual Address DelAddress { get; set; }
        public virtual Address POAddress { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public bool InActive { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public string Phone1 { get; set; }
        public string Phone2 { get; set; }
    }
```

But I did see quite a few examples using ForeignID as a reference for field such as Address and I am using a directly reference to an Address Object in my Model. I think using reference is better because I am dealing with Objects at this level but not records or DB level which will end up referenced by an ID anyway. But still, what would you use for your Code First Model?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I link a model to another model in MVC3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194146/how-should-i-link-a-model-to-another-model-in-mvc3)

Comment: @Eranga, thanks for the link, so the short answer is better using both? Doesn't make much sense to me?

Comment: Yes. It will make sense when you start using this class in your application :)

Comment: @Eranga consider it as design flaw in Entity FrameWork?

Comment: No. Each one is useful in different situations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code First: Independent associations vs. Foreign key associations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281974/code-first-independent-associations-vs-foreign-key-associations)

Comment: @Ladislav, gread write up in your article. Yes, your conclusion make sense to me, and present both options will create confusion for newbie like me. It not that I don't like options which I can choose, but I am yet see the necessity of Foreign Key reference, but is used by lots of examples. and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686875/c-sharp-entity-framework-should-we-set-a-relationship-by-using-the-poco-id-or-ju actually recommend POCO reference aginst POCO.Id.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all other things are equal, object references are better because the "noise" of "soft" ID-based references pollute your model.

That said, all other thing's aren't equal as Ladislav writes in [Foreign key vs. Independent associations in EF 4](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/05/foreign-key-vs-independent-associations-in-ef-4/). For example, independent associations require you have both ends of the relationship in memory. This can be a bit problematic when saving updates in that you have to load the target of a relationship when you otherwise wouldn't in order for it to be in the `ObjectStateManager`. This is a particular pain when saving an entity that has many reference to "reference data" type entities and when working in an N-tier architecture.

Both work *mostly ok* but their implementations aren't complete and don't have parity. So *better* can't be answered with complete certainty without a more rigorous analysis your usage patterns, architecture, and performance requirements.

Comment: Yes, agree 'better' means nothing unless I defined my requirements or with a metrics for thing I care about. As I am starting using Entity Framework for my first major project. How about 1.easy of use, i.e. make entity useful without too much work and confusing and 2.reliable, i.e. always working in obviously way without throw unexpected exceptions and 3.flexible, which is little bit hard to define. But I do not want if EF team changed their implementation, or I changed my mind(which is probably a moot point anyway) and decided using one over the other, there are no obvious bad consequences?